# Weird crash while pinching UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

This issue has been driving me nuts for the past few hours. So I've got a very simple UIScrollView setup:

```
-UIScrollView
    -UIImageView
```

That's it. The scrollview and imageview are generated in Storyboard. Now all I want to do is to have the ability to pinch zoom into this image. Minimum zoom is set to 1 and maximum zoom is 3. The scrollview's delegate is set to my RootViewController

In my RootViewController, I have added this function(Required to support zooming)

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   return _theImageView;
}
```

I believe I've done everything right but whenever I pinch the scrollview, I get the great EXE_BAD_ACCESS. I've tried to look everywhere and I can't seem to find the issue. Crash dump attached below

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34b80f7e objc_msgSend + 22
1   UIKit                           0x3516899e -[UIScrollView _getDelegateZoomView] + 70
2   UIKit                           0x351908f2 -[UIScrollView _zoomScaleFromPresentationLayer:] + 22
3   UIKit                           0x3523bf5a -[UIScrollViewPinchGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 102
4   UIKit                           0x35102436 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 278
5   UIKit                           0x351021ee -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 82
6   UIKit                           0x350e868e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350
7   UIKit                           0x350e7f34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
8   GraphicsServices                0x32c85224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
```

What am I doing wrong?

Maybe I'm too sleepy

Comment: What do you see if you use `NSLog(@"%@", _theImageView);` before returning it?

Comment: That's the funny thing, it doesn't matter. I tried adding a breakpoint to the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` function but it's not breaking there at all. The crash is occurring before that.

Comment: How about running with Instruments set for Zombie detection?

Comment: It looks to me like somehow your delegate got deallocated. Have you confirmed that your delegate is referencing your (current) RootViewController, and not another deallocated instance somehow?

Comment: @gschandler Yes, I'm pretty sure it's the RVC. Anyway, it's the same VC that's being shown in the window right now, that can't get dealloced right?  @Phillip With zombies turned on, I get this in the console `*** -[RootViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a48730`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this the next morning after looking at the code with a fresh pair of eyes. I have a `MainViewController` initializing and added `RootViewController` to it's subview. The issue was that this was a _weak reference and ARC was dealloc-ing it.

Assigned it as a global _strong variable on `MainViewController` and all was fixed.

Comment: You might want to "vote" for the answer... your stackoverflow reputation will thank you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue, solved it by adding the following in the dealloc of the view controller:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = nil;
self.scrollView = nil;
```

And I'm using ARC so it seems redundant, but it definitely solves the issue.
I suspect that this is the cause of the issue:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate>      delegate;                       // default nil. weak reference
```

From the `UIScrollView.h` file

Comment: you should use weak keyword instead of assign in the property declaration when you are using ARC

Comment: you mean Apple should

Comment: Awesome and tricky solution! Saved me a lot of time, thanks! ;) Btw: You don't need to set the `scrollView` itself to nil because for that object ARC is doing its job...

Comment: now it is `@property(nullable,nonatomic,weak) id<UIScrollViewDelegate>        delegate;`

Answer (score 0):

What is `_theView`? If it's your `UIScrollView`, then you need to do this:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [_theView viewForZoomingInScrollView:scrollView];
}
```

Also, you don't necessarily need this at all. Pinch-zooming should work automatically, unless you explicitly set the scroll view's delegate; if you do this, pinch-zooming should still work automatically in iOS 5, so you would only need to implement `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` for this to work in iOS 4.

Comment: That was a typo. I've fixed it now. It's referring to the _imageView that I wanna zoom into. But when I set a breakpoint there, that function isn't being called at all. The crash is happening before that.

Comment: You need to set your scroll view's delegate property to self - otherwise these methods will never be called.

Comment: The scrollview's delegate is already set to RootViewController via storyboard. I just tested the app with & without the delegate linking, same crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out the minimum zoom scale for the scroll view. A zoom scale of one means that the content is displayed at normal size. A zoom scale below one shows the content zoomed out, while a zoom scale of greater than one shows the content zoomed in. To get the minimum zoom scale, you calculate how far you’d need to zoom out so that the image fits snugly in your scroll view’s bounds based on its width. Then you do the same based upon the image’s height. The minimum of those two resulting zoom scales will be the scroll view’s minimum zoom scale. That gives you a zoom scale where you can see the entire image when fully zoomed out.

Swift:

```
let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
```

Objective-C

```
CGFloat scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
CGFloat minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
```

From other projects and personal experience doing heavy GPU on the iOS (endless scroll, maximum bitmap size, etc), I've noticed that each device has it's own threshold.  For past projects, I've also hardcoded the below values as the minimumZoomScale to prevent the crashes:

```
scale :
        {
                iPad : {
                    min : 0.8
                ,   max : 1.6
            }
            , iPhone : {
                    min : 0.25
                ,   max : 1.6
            }
            , iPhone6 : {
                    min : 0.3333
                ,   max : 1.6
            }
            , iPhoneResizable: {
                    min : 1
                ,   max : 1.6
            }
        }
```

Great tutorial for beginners: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift